# What is wrong with this programming?

Tags: python

This keeps bugging me with an error which I will state at the end:

```
import math
# Target:
# Enter an input and it will convert into GB, MB and KB with the leftover bytes in it
def start():
print ''
print ''
# 10 = 1 billion
byte = input("Bytes: ")
tw = int(math.log10(byte))+1
tw = tw - 7
gb = byte // 10**9
byte = str(byte)
a = len(byte) - 6
b = len(byte) - 3
if b > 0:
    if a > 0:
        kb = int(str(byte)[a:b])

    else:
        kd = int(str(byte)[0:b])
else:
    kb = 0
c = len(byte) - 6
if c > 1:   
    mb = int(str(byte)[0:c])
    if int(mb) > 999:
        if int(mb) < 10000:
            mb = mb // 10**3
            byte = str(byte)
            if len(byte) <= 3:
                mb = 0
                kb = 0
else:
    mb = 0 

d = len(byte) - 6
byte = int(byte)
lob = int(str(byte)[d:])
byte = str(byte)
if int(kb) > 1000:
    dmb = mb // 10**3
    mb = mb + dmb
    kb = kb // 10**3 
print ''
print ''
print ''
print('     GB: %s MB: %s KB: %s') % (gb, mb, kb)
print('     Bytes: %s') % lob
print ''
print ''
print ''
start()
```

What is wrong with this?
It keeps saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bytes.py", line 53, in <module>
start()
File "bytes.py", line 39, in start
if int(kb) > 1000:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kb' referenced before assignment
```

What's wrong?! I
I keep changing line 39 to different places, but I'm not sure how I fix it?
With the UnboundLocalError, I can't figure out how local variable 'kb' referenced before assignment. Help!

Comment: You have a code path where you only assign to `kd`, never to `kb`. Presumably this is a typo. (Using good variable names would have made this much easier to spot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from several ugly antipatterns, there's one obvious mistake/typo: Take a good look at

```
if a > 0:
    kb = int(str(byte)[a:b])

else:
    kd = int(str(byte)[0:b])
```

Do you see now where your error comes from?

Comment: Sorry this is OFF-TOPIC do not read